# PartialViewContext: What the difference between isAjaxRequest and isPartialRequest

Tags: jsf-2

I'm extending jsf 2 with a custom `PartialViewContext`, and I don't understand the difference between the two methods`isAjaxRequest` and `isPartialRequest.

```
public abstract boolean isAjaxRequest();
```

> Return true if the request header Faces-Request is present with the value partial/ajax. Otherwise, return false.

```
public abstract boolean isPartialRequest();
```

> Return true isAjaxRequest returns true or if the request header Faces-Request is present 
>   with the value partial/process. Otherwise, return false.

I can't figure out what this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code, the difference is:

```
public boolean isAjaxRequest() {
    return "partial/ajax".equals(request.getHeader("faces-request"));
}

public boolean isPartialRequest() {
    return isAjaxRequest() || "partial/process".equals(request.getHeader("faces-request"));
}
```

Exactly as described by the Javadoc.

Your next (or actual?) question shall probably be *"When would they return true and when would they be used?"*. Well, the `isPartialRequest()` is actually a further abstraction of `isAjaxRequest()`. It is namely quite possible that some different kind of HTTP request is invented in the future which would require JSF to return a partial response. Among others the [`PartialResponseWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/PartialResponseWriter.html) is relying on that. This way the JSF guys doesn't need to change that API when such a new type of HTTP request is introduced.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, there is rarely any need to explicitly override them yourselves. You can just keep the standard implementation as is. Are you aware of the [`PartialViewContextWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/PartialViewContextWrapper.html)? If you extend from it, then you don't need to implement those methods yourself.